# How to set a variable in xaml

Tags: xaml

I have a MoveThumb class that extends Thumb, and I have a member integer m_iIndex that I want to set in xaml in this kind of way...

```
<s:MoveThumb x:Name="LeftRightControl" 
  Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}"
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
  Cursor="SizeAll" 
  Index="2"/>
```

code behind:

```
    public class MoveThumb : Thumb, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int m_iIndex;

        public int Index
        {
            get
            {
                return m_iIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                m_iIndex = value;
            }
        }
        ...
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You've done it. With `Index="2"`. Maybe your question is _"How to do it on a existing instance of `MoveThumb`?"_ ?

Comment: It can't find the Index property though. Error list says 'The property 'Index' was not found in the type 'MoveThumb' How do I register it so I can use Index in xaml?

Comment: You don't have to register it. A property should be clearly visible from the XAML.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the error. On my computer it compiles correctly. Maybe, you can try to clean your project, recompile twice (it can solve some problems with XAML) or restart Visual Studio. The namespace alias `s` points to the correct namespace?

Comment: Clean and rebuild did it, thanks!

Comment: Also to note, sometimes Intellisense will show XAML errors then when you close it, the error goes away...